# Processor-in-the-loop for the design of a diagnosis system

Tags: design, hardware

I'm studying the development and implementation of a diagnosis system. I would like to understand what is the processor-in-the-loop, but there isn't any Wikipedia page (while there are for hardware-in-the-loop and software-in-the-loop).
Could you explain that to me?

Comment: What is a "diagnose system"?

Comment: What diagnose system? Medical diagnose? Technical (car, engine,...) diagnose?...

Comment: It's a generic one, let's suppose an electro-mechanical process

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure you can see that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: perhaps you need to read information at other places besides Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7530751

"Processor in the loop" means the control system is running through a processor which simulates the plant.

"Hardware in the loop" means the control system is actually controlling real plant hardware.

Comment: I know nothing more than what is stated here because I just googled it and parroted back the link.

Comment: I think that in the hardware in the loop the control system controls an hardware surrogate of the real plant hardware. Is this correct ?

Comment: @themagiciant95 I wouldn't know.